# Fermentation stuck on 1.020

Tags: fermentation

Here is the question. I brewed an IPA:

- 0.25 kg Dark Munich
- 0.25 kg Caramel 40 L
- 0.50 kg Wheat
- 5.00 kg Pilsner
- SG 1.065

Really wanted to try Giga Vermont yeast golden pitch (you can pitch one pack for 5 gallons) it has double cell count, but 72 hours no activity, no foam building, nothing.

I didn’t have any yeast around, luckily my friend had some 05 slurry about 150 ml, so I pitched that fermentation started in about 18 hours.I have temperature controlled setup so it’s always steady.It was fermenting for about a week and stuck on 1.020.

Question is can I pitch some more Safale 05  to see if it will ferment to desire 1010 or just leave it like it is, keg it and that’s it. I never had before experience to repitch the yeast many times.

Please share your thoughts.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4):

**Mix it up and get it warm.** Swirl the fermentor to break up yeast floculation and increase temp to 75°F or even higher. This will help lazy yeast to wake up again.

*You may already be at terminal gravity.*
Your grist here has about 10% dextrin malts which are unfermentable. Also mash temp is critical for wort fermentability, too hot will make less fermentable wort.

Comment: Indeed, 1.020 could be the Final Gravity.

Comment: Thanx for the replay,The mashing was done at 67C.

Comment: @Iacovlev that's about 153°F unless it was gradually stepped up to this temp, only alpha-amylase was doing the work and is generally a good blend of fermentable and unfermentable sugars. It is possible it's at TG still, try to mix and warm to get it to clean up more though.

Comment: Thank you , if gravity not going to change can I try a fresh pack of yeast?

Comment: @Iacovlev you can try, but in my experience pitching unconditioned fresh yeast this close to or at TG doesn't have good results.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep higher temp. for two days then take hydrometer reading.Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that it was a bit under pitched. If the slurry was from another batch, the yeast could be in bad health condition and the cell count is hard to estimate.

I would just give it a kick, as in literally kick it or shake the fermentation a bit, so the yeast from the bottom get stirred up. Try avoiding splashing though. If this doesn't change anything in a few days, it is possible to pitch more yeast.

Kegging it now probably result in a sweet, unfinished beer. There is also the chance of exploding bottles but this might not be a problem in case of kegging.

How big was the batch? 5 gall of 1.065 is quite a big job for one pack of yeast. No experience with giga yeast but I know the wyeast smackpacks are able to ferment up to 5 gall 1.060. And those are advertised as 'XL smackpacks'...

Comment: Batch was 5.5 gallons , I will wait a week let’s see if it will go down a bit.I will swirl the fermenter a bit as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try some [Pro Restart](http://www.scottlab.com/product-100.aspx) encapsulated yeast. It's a wine product, but there isn't any reason it wouldn't work on a stuck beer.

Answer (score 0):

Pitch US-05 or US-04 pack for 2 weeks at 68 to 70 degrees. Did you oxygenate wort?   Ferment at too high temperature you could get 'banana' type off flavors. Brewdog333